# Improve cython array indexing speed

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

I'm have a pretty simple function which I need to speed up.  Essentially I have a big array of 16 bit numbers with some holes in it.  (About 10%)  I need to traverse the array, find areas where there are 2 0's in a row, then fill them in with the average of the previous and next elements.  This takes only a few milliseconds in C, but Python is doing way worse.

I've switched from regular python arrays to numpy arrays, and then compiled my code using cython, but I'm still really far from my target.  I was hoping someone with more experience might look at what I'm doing and give me some feedback.

My regular python code looks like this:

```
self.rawData = numpy.fromfile(ql, numpy.uint16, 50000)
[snip]
def fixZeroes(self):
    for x in range(2,len(self.rawData)):
        if self.rawData[x] == 0 and self.rawData[x-1] == 0:
            self.rawData[x] = (self.rawData[x-2] + self.rawData[x+2]) / 2
            self.rawData[x-1] = (self.rawData[x-3] + self.rawData[x+1]) /2
```

My Cython code looks very similar:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
DTYPE = np.uint16
ctypedef np.uint16_t DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def fix_zeroes(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] raw):
    assert raw.dtype == DTYPE
    cdef int len = 50000
    
    for x in range(2,len):
        if raw[x] == 0 and raw[x-1] == 0:
            raw[x] = (raw[x-2] + raw[x+2]) / 2
        raw[x-1] = (raw[x-3] + raw[x+1]) /2
    return raw
```

When I run this code, the performance is still way slower than I'd like:

> Starting cython zero fix
>
> Finished: 0:00:36.983681
>
> starting python zero fix
>
> Finished: 0:00:41.434476

I really think I must be doing something wrong.  Most every article I've seen talks about the huge performance gains numpy and cython add, but I'm barely breaking 10%.

Comment: `This takes only a few milliseconds in C`. Do you have the C function? If so, just wrap that directly in Cython and call it from your Python program.

Comment: @ThaneBrimhall using Cython with all the boosting directives and type declarations should get very close to C

Comment: @ThaneBrimhall - Good point.  I have a C function, but it's a mess.  I needed to rewrite the algorithm this is a part of anyway, so that's why it's getting ported to python.  I do like your suggestion though.

Comment: @SaulloCastro Yeah, I know. But I'm lazy and if I already have something done, I usually just reuse it. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should declare the `x` variable that you are using to index the `raw` array:

```
cdef int x
```

you can also use other directives that usually provide a performance boost:

```
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
```

Comment: Wow!  Yeah, that was the problem.  I went from 36.9 seconds to .0072 seconds.  I'd call that a win.

Comment: @MaxwellBottiger Great, keep in mind these directives! Another thing you may face in the future is to replace `x**2` by `x*x`, since the first will be transformed in a function call, sth like `pow(x, 2)`